# How do I configure my Docker React container to only install modules when it needs them?

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, npm-install

I'm trying to build several Docker services in my docker-compose.yml file that would launch my Django/MySql backend as well as my React client application.  I have this section in my docker-compose.yml to deal with the React portion ....

```
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
    ports:
      - '3001:3000'
    restart: always
    container_name: web-app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_PROXY=http://localhost:9090
    depends_on:
      - web
```

Then I have built the following client/Dockerfile to configure the React container ...

```
FROM node:10-alpine AS alpine

# A directory within the virtualized Docker environment
# Becomes more relevant when using Docker Compose later
WORKDIR /app/

# Copies package.json and package-lock.json to Docker environment
COPY package*.json ./

# Installs all node packages
RUN npm install

# Finally runs the application
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

But when my container starts up, it dies with the below error ...

```
web-app   | Failed to compile.
web-app   | 
web-app   | ./node_modules/react-tag-input/dist-modules/components/ReactTags.js
web-app   | Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dnd' in '/app/node_modules/react-tag-input/dist-modules/components'
```

I thought my "RUN npm install" above would save the day, but I guess not.  Is there a way to somehow detect what modules aren't installed and install them when my container launches?

**Edit:** package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^1.9.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.12.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-hamburger-menu": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.15",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.1",
    "react-tag-input": "^6.4.3",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=development react-scripts build",
    "build:prod": "NODE_ENV=production react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your `package.json` ?

Comment: @nischay goyal, it is added as an edit to my question

Comment: Just want to check whether `react-dnd` should be part of package.json or not? If not, Can you add the output of `docker build -t imageName .`

Comment: @nischay goyal, yes it should be in there.  I was trying to get the component from here -- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tag-input , to work but didn't follow the installation properly.  Evidently running "npm install --save react-tag-input" doesn't install all the dependencies and I had to go in there and install those individually.

Comment: I think you need to add all of your dependencies in package.json properly and then run the npm install and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things are happening here:

1. Your `volumes:` directive overwrites everything in the `/app` tree, including `node_modules`.
2. Your Dockerfile doesn't actually `COPY` the application code into the image (so you need the workaround of using `volumes:` to put it there).

You can fix this by updating your Dockerfile

```sh
FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /app/
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Actually copy the application code in
COPY . ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

If you don't already have a `.dockerignore` file, create it containing the line `node_modules`, to keep that host directory from being built into the image.

Finally, delete the `volumes:` from your `docker-compose.yml` file.

If you change your front-end code, you will need to `docker-compose up --build` to cause the image to be rebuilt.

If you want a live-development environment, you can use Node directly on the host, even if most of the rest of your stack is running in Docker.  This is especially true for front-end code: since the code that's being served actually runs in the end user's browser, it can't directly communicate with Docker networking or otherwise really take advantage of being in Docker at all.

```sh
# Start everything besides the front-end
docker-compose up -d web

# Start a dev server in the usual way
export NODE_ENV=development
export REACT_APP_PROXY=http://localhost:9090
npm start
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider the `COPY` option for code until and unless, he copied the partial Dockerfile

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, Thanks for this insightful answer.  I would like to maintain the ability to edit a file locally in my client (frontend) project and have the docker image automatically re-compile the app.  If I implement your solution, won't I have to rebuild my docker image each time I edit a file in my frontend application?